# SSL in Kivy for android development

Tags: android, python, ssl, kivy, buildozer

I was developing a mobile app that can send mqtt messages to AWS Iot. It needs paho-mqtt library. It can be included in buildozer.spec requirements. My problem is in the SSL part, because I need to import SSL in the code which seems to have a problem with the python version running in python-for-android, which is 2.7.2.

The code is below, which works fine on the PC, but on th phone it is not working.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


import paho.mqtt.publish as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttclient  
#


class MqttTest(App):
    def build(self):
        topic = "topic1"
        my_ca_cert  = "RootCA.pem"
        my_pri_cert = "my.cert.pem"
        my_key_cert = "my.private.key"


        try:
            import ssl
            mqttc = mqttclient.Client("Python_Ex_Pub")
            mqttc.tls_set(my_ca_cert, 
                certfile=my_pri_cert, 
                keyfile=my_key_cert,
                cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, 
                tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, 
                ciphers=None)
            mqttc.connect("myaddress", 8883)
            mqttc.publish(topic, "This is a test pub from Python.")

            return Label(text="Hi it works!")
        except Exception as e:
            import traceback
            a=traceback.format_exc()
            try:
                f1=open("/storage/emulated/0/Download/err.txt","w")
                f1.write(str(a))
                f1.close()
            except:
                pass
            return Label(text=str (a))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MqttTest().run()
```

without adding anything related to SSL in buildozer.spec requirements, I get the following error:

```
no module named _ssl
```

If I added openssl as one of the requirements, then I get the following error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'
```

Comment: Do you need to use 2.7.2 specifically? Kivy supports both python 2.7 and 3, doesn't it? Seems like `PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` was added in 2.7.9 (and then deprecated in 2.7.13).

Comment: no, but I just haven't tried python3 on kivy and python 4 android. So How I can do this?

Comment: The Kivy FAQ says _"As of version 1.8.0 Kivy supports both Python >= 2.7 and Python >= 3.3 with the same codebase. Python 3 is also now supported by python-for-android."_

Answer (score 1):

As noted `PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` was added in later Python 2 version than p4a provides.

You can try to build apk with Python 3:

1. Change your buildozer's `requirements` line replacing `python2` with `python3crystax`
2. Download and unpack crystax ndk [here](https://www.crystax.net/en/download)
3. Change your buildozer's `android.ndk_path` to point unpacked crystax ndk directory
4. Run `buildozer android debug`

If you're lucky enough you'll be able to build apk with Python 3 without any other actions.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have followed this procedure to run python3 on android, I guess it works but still no ssl defined there. check this link, I have added this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988365/ssl-in-python3-using-buildozer-for-android

I have also printed the python version to make sure python3 is running

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar issue. I am trying to import pydrive without doing anything at first. Below is from logcat.

I tried 3 os environment, osx, ubuntu, bulldozer vm. All give me the same error.

I/python  (13323):    File "/Users/macuser/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2/**init**.py", line 960, in 
I/python  (13323):  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'

In httplib.py, i found below code.

```
try:
    import ssl
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    class HTTPSConnection(HTTPConnection):
        "This class allows communication via SSL."
```

So I suspect ssl not import successfully. Then, check ssl.py and found PROTOCOL_SSLv3 cannot import successfully.

```
from _ssl import PROTOCOL_SSLv3, PROTOCOL_SSLv23, PROTOCOL_TLSv1
```

Until here i am not able to proceed further. I am using python3crystax and it still not work as claim in this post.

Since buildozer will download all library separately, i suspect python automatically downloaded by bulldozer is a python version that doesn't include ssl3 support.

Comment: This does not look like an answer to the original question - if you're looking for help for your problem, please open a new question